# How do I make a login dialog stick to the top of the page in one line in CSS like Facebook's sign-in page?

Tags: css, html, authentication, passwords

I'm working on a project and I need to find a way to make a username and password dialog box stick to the top of the page, like the image below. I'm still learning CSS at this stage. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

[image: In-line login]

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: @SpeKtra Do you want the bar to be "fixed" to the top of the page (as in, what Facebook currently uses on their actual feed pages -- not scrollable), or do you simply just want it to sit on top of the page above your main content, and scroll with that content?

Comment: Simply want it to sit on top of the page above my main content. I'm very new to CSS.

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it with [`header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) and then

```
header {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;  /* if you want to stick it on top then set top : 0 */
}
```

***sidenote:*** set `position:fixed` if you want to make this stick always on top of the window while scroll down.

```css
header{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fe4;
    color:#444;
    padding:4px;
    font:normal 14px verdana;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow :1.5px 2.5px #eef;
}
header >form { display:inline; }
button {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
       <!-- Markup for your login bar -->
        <header>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <label for="username">Email:</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required />
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required />
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>     
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/17Lv6tk3/2/

Give below style to Main div

```
 style="Float:rigth"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use to set the display:inline property, the html should be something like this:

```
<div class="top_login">
<span>Email</span> <div> <input type="text" name="email"> </div>
<span>password</span> <div> <input type="password" name="password"> </div>
<button>Login</button>
</div>
```

and the style

```
.top_login{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.top_login div{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it stick to the top left of page, right in the corner like the image?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the login bar to sit above your main content area, it's as simple as putting the HTML markup for the login bar above the HTML markup for the page content:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- Markup for your login bar -->
        <div class="login-bar">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <label for="username">User Name:</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>

                <label for="username">Password</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="password"/>

                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>     
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <!-- Your page content goes here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some advice for you since you're new to CSS:  Never try to overdo it with CSS.  Less is more.  Sometimes there are more elegant solutions that require less code, and will save you maintenance issues in the future.  Explore all the possibilities first.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it stick to the top left of page, right in the corner like the image?